# How to fix formatting date when converting it to json encode in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to fix format of date in json encode. I want the format of m/d/y

```
    $schedule = Schedule::where('doctor_id', '10')->pluck('day', 'id')->toArray();
    //output of dates in schedule model are 11/21/2022,11/22/2022
    $data2[] = [
        'user_id' => 'My name',
        'dates' => $schedule
    ];

    return view('admin.appointment.create', compact('data2'));
```

this is the output I get when passing it to JavaScript

```
var datas = @json($data2);

//output
[{"user_id":"My name","dates":{"7":"11\/21\/2022","10":"11\/22\/2022"}}]
```

Comment: Try [`var datas = JSON.parse(@json($data2))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse('[{"user_id":"My name","dates":{"7":"11\/21\/2022","10":"11\/22\/2022"}}]'))` equates to: `[
  {
    user_id: 'My name',
    dates: { '7': '11/21/2022', '10': '11/22/2022' }
  }
]
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Comment: JSON.stringify(datas) works to me

Comment: What about? `var datas = JSON.parse('@json($data2)')` Note the *single quotes* around `@json(...)`

Comment: yes that's what I do and it works